# Can I draw vertical lines on the LineSeries Graph?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm making an application with some OxyPlot Graphs.

I want to make a graph that has a vertical line on the LineSeries Graph like this link:

http://theclosetentrepreneur.com/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-an-excel-xy-chart

(My ideal image is in "Tips on formatting your chart…".)

How can I make this graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of LineAnnotation for the purpose. For example,

```
var annotation = new LineAnnotation();
annotation.Color = OxyColors.Blue;
annotation.MinimumY = 10;
annotation.MaximumY = 40;
annotation.X = 5;
annotation.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
annotation.Type = LineAnnotationType.Vertical;
MyPlotModel.Annotations.Add(annotation);
```

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks your comment! This is my ideal graph! Your answer is perfect, really thank you! XD

Comment: @siksmtt Glad to help you. Cheers